# Is it possible to change a permission level based on the creator of the content?

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions

Currently using a SharePoint 2013 installation and I was wondering whether it is possible for a given document in a library to be available to someone based on the permissions of the creator?

```
Creator    |Company X permissions |Company Y permissions
           |                      |
Company X  |Read and Edit         |Read
Company Y  |Read and Edit         |Read and Edit
```

Comment: Can you explain further ?